# How to enable access in Google Cloud Storage to `x-goog-hash` header from client side (browser)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want my client side to access the `x-goog-hash` header. but I can not, probably because of the Google Cloud Storage defenition.
I know there is a way to allow accessing that header in the Google Cloud Storage.
Does anyone know how to do it?
These are the headers I have an access to:

```
    "headers": {
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "content-length": "0",
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        "date": "Tue, 01 Mar 2022 09:22:11 GMT",
        "server": "UploadServer",
        "x-guploader-uploadid": "ADPycdvmU7_-9wqmePl5m_jzzdCWmr84AZwEbv2SJJ99kJLkq2eYzpQqrMaK4mHu_RiNVI3WzTkVH5Y"
    },
```

the `x-goog-hash` does not appear here,
but I expect to get this header, as you can see in the image below.

[image: image of response headers]